# How to replace Specific values of a particular column in Pandas Dataframe based on a certain condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe which contains students and percentages of marks obtained by them. There are some students whose marks are shown as greater than 100%. Obviously these values are incorrect and I would like to replace all percentage values which are greater than 100% by NaN.

I have tried on some code but not quite able to get exactly what I would like to desire.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

new_DF = pd.DataFrame({'Student' : ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'],
                       'Percentages' : [85, 70, 101, 55, 120]})

#  Percentages  Student
#0          85       S1
#1          70       S2
#2         101       S3
#3          55       S4
#4         120       S5
```

```
new_DF[(new_DF.iloc[:, 0] > 100)] = np.NaN

#  Percentages  Student
#0        85.0       S1
#1        70.0       S2
#2         NaN      NaN
#3        55.0       S4
#4         NaN      NaN
```

As you can see the code kind of works but it actually replaces all the values in that particular row where Percentages is greater than 100 by NaN. I would only like to replace the value in Percentages column by NaN where its greater than 100. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and use [`np.where`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+where&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+where&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1856j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
new_DF.Percentages=np.where(new_DF.Percentages.gt(100),np.nan,new_DF.Percentages)
```

or

```
new_DF.loc[new_DF.Percentages.gt(100),'Percentages']=np.nan
```

---

```
print(new_DF)

  Student  Percentages
0      S1         85.0
1      S2         70.0
2      S3          NaN
3      S4         55.0
4      S5          NaN
```

Comment: @JohnE yes , also depends on the size of df i think? for larger dfs shouldnt np.where work faster? BDW uncommented now. :) Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.  Generally `np.where` is very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Also,

```
df.Percentages = df.Percentages.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x>100 else x)
```

or,

```
df.Percentages = df.Percentages.where(df.Percentages<100, np.nan)
```

Comment: This will work too. :) However avoid apply when you can , its slow.

Comment: Agree with @anky_91, try to avoid `.apply` when its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
new_DF.loc[new_DF['Percentages']>100, 'Percentages'] = np.NaN
```

Output:

```
  Student  Percentages
0      S1         85.0
1      S2         70.0
2      S3          NaN
3      S4         55.0
4      S5          NaN
```

Comment: this is already there in my solution(check commented part) not sure how is this any different

Comment: Understood now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

new_DF = pd.DataFrame({'Student' : ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'],
                      'Percentages' : [85, 70, 101, 55, 120]})
#print(new_DF['Student'])
index=-1
for i in new_DF['Percentages']:
    index+=1
    if i > 100:
        new_DF['Percentages'][index] = "nan"




print(new_DF)
```